# Allocating memory to context when using spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I start start spark shell using :

```
./bin/spark-shell --master spark://IP:7077 --executor-memory 4G
```

Then no memory is allocated to Spark :

[image]

If however if I just use default :

```
./bin/spark-shell --master spark://IP:7077
```

then memory is allocated :

[image]

> How can I use max available memory in spark shell ? In this case
>   845MB+845MB+2.8GB = 4.49GB

Update : It appears Spark will just allocate to each node the max available memory of the node with the least amount of memory. So if I use :

```
./bin/spark-shell --master spark://IP:7077 --executor-memory 845M
```

then 2 nodes are fully allocated but node with 2.8GB is not fully allocated :

[image]

So question now becomes can Spark be configured so that each node uses it's max free memory ?

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster consists of machines of different types, the limit of memory allocated to all executors will be taken from the machine with least memory size.

Spark is not that smart of allocating more memory to one specific executor because it runs on a bigger machine. That's why it's recommended to use homogenous hardware to build spark/hadoop cluster.

Secondly, try to avoid allocating 100% node's memory to executors because it will make GC collection slower & also other daemons needs memory too. My suggestion would be to spare at least 5% memory size on every single machine.

For more insights I recommend this article http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Hope it helps.